# Match grep output to values in file

Tags: grep, aix, pid

I have a file name clfile.me that looks like this;

```
44433430,"FALSE"
33095934,"TRUE"
41549968,"TRUE"
37945528,"FALSE"
18284764,"FALSE"
15007934,"FALSE"
```

The number is AIX PID. I have a command that will match the PIDs to a running process.

```
while read p; do
    ps -ef | grep $p | grep 'myproram' | grep -v grep | awk "{ print \$2 }" >> clout.me
done < clfile.me
```

THe above works but only shows me the PID that matched from the grep command. I want to be able to see the matching PID and the TRUE or FALSE value from the original file. I guess I am asking how I filter the original file by PIDs that match my grep command.

Any thoughts?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: please edit your post to include required sample output. Too hard to tell what you mean by "now need to maintain the T F ..." Good luck.

Comment: As requested, I have added more detail...THe above works but only shows me the PID that matched from the grep command. I want to be able to see the matching PID and the TRUE or FALSE value from the original file. I guess I am asking how I filter the original file by PIDs that match my grep command.

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while, but I have it!

```
cat /dev/null > clout.me
while read p; do
    x=$(awk '{ print $1 }')
    ps -ef | grep x | grep 'myprogram' | grep -v grep | awk "{ print \$2 }" >> clout.me
done < clfile.me

awk 'FNR==NR{A[$1]=1;next} A[$1]' clout.me clfile.me
```